# R CMD BATCH [options]

Tags: r

I'm hoping to find a list of the available *[options]* for **R CMD BATCH**.  The [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/BATCH.html) is not especially helpful and doesn't link to anything else.

I may have just missed the right **R** help file, but any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: On Linux `R --help`.

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Thank you.